# Common base large signal transfer characteristics

Tags: bjt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyXpYL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to draw the large transfer characteristics for this common base BJT below. I redrew figure 1 to look like figure 2 so it can help better visualize what's going.
I want to plot Vo Vs Vi

I used KVL to come up with this equation
-Vcc + RLIc + Vo + Vi = 0

So then Vo = Vcc -RLIc - Vi

Ic = Is x e(Vbe/Vt)

Vo = Vcc - [Is x e(Vbe/Vt)RL) - Vi

My confusion is that the base is grounded. Does this now mean that Vbe = -Vi? Or is it that Vbe = 0 since the base is grounded?

If Vbe = 0 then Vo = Vcc - (IsRL) - Vi

Or Vbe = 0 -Vi then Vo = Vcc - [Is x e(-Vi/Vt)RL] -Vi.
Can you please tell me what's right here? Or maybe I get it all wrong then I will need some guidance.
Thanks!

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question more readable. Note on EE we start and end inline Mathjax with `\$` instead of just `$`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this now mean that Vbe = -Vi? Or is it that Vbe = 0 since the base is grounded?

\$V_{be} = V_b - V_e\$

So yes, in your diagram, \$V_{be}\$ is \$-V_i\$.

\$V_{be}\$ is only equal to 0 if the base and emitter are at the same potential.

Comment: Yes, I thought so but I wasn't quite sure. Thanks!